# How do I pass all existing parameters into route blade function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I use the `route` function to generate URL's in my blade templates to create links on the fly for my links.

Example
<a href="{{ route('admin.users.archives') }}" class="btn btn-primary" aria-current="page" @endif>Archives

I am using some Laravel packages which add URL parameters to the page however, the number of parameters can grow/reduce.

How can I update the `route` function to include all page parameters in a clean way?
I've tried appending `->appends(request()->query())`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: you would pass the array from `query` to the route helper, second argument, which would append all those parameters as query string parameters (if they don't match up to route parameters)

Comment: you could make your own helper function that you can call that will do this for you as well